# VS Coded UI Tests on Linux/Mono

Tags: linux, mono, coded-ui-tests

Someone knows if VS Coded UI Tests run under Linux using Mono ??
Dont have a testsetup on my hand to test this fast :/

Comment: what UI? WPF? System.Windows.Forms?

Comment: does that matter ? i just started to get into coded UI Tests, and actually it seems it uses just to "simulate" user inputs like mouse and keyboard. i am using MonoGame

Comment: of course it matters, because WPF wouldn't work in Linux

Answer (score 0):

Coded-UI does not support any OS other than Windows.

You can find it here. [Supported Configurations and Platforms for Coded UI Tests and Action Recordings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380742.aspx)

> **Supported Operating Systems:**
>
> Operating Systems Windows 7
>
> Windows Server 2008 R2
>
> Windows 8
>
> Windows 10